# how to create backslash effect on div with css

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to create this effect with CSS:

[image: target effect]

I got the red line and it is a simple div.

Does anyone know a way for getting this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example on https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/, I have used -45deg to create a "backslash" and blue instead but it should explain the concept. Use this as a basis to create a more complex background for your div:

```css
div {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    #606dbc,
    #606dbc 10px,
    #465298 10px,
    #465298 20px
  );  
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

Learn more about the [repeating-linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient).